# Pass user-defined table type "on the fly" into stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

If I have a stored procedure that uses a user-defined table as one of its inputs, is there any way to call the stored procedure without declaring the variable beforehand?

i.e. I have this type:

```
CREATE TYPE [IDs] AS TABLE
(
    [ID] [BIGINT] NULL
)
```

and this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDoSomething (@IDs IDs)
AS
...
```

Normally, this would be called by declaring the table variable first:

```
DECLARE @IDs IDs
INSERT @IDs VALUES (1),(2)
EXEC spDoSomething @IDs
```

Is there any way to call this in one line, i.e.

```
EXEC spDoSomething @IDs = (SELECT 1 AS ID UNION ALL SELECT 2)
```

Use case is that I am accessing the database through a UI, which builds the SQL dynamically and doing a `DECLARE @IDs...` is not possible

Comment: *"Is there any way to call this in one line"* No, you must define the parameter prior; there is no way around that.

Comment: You have the short answer. The longer answer is you create a "wrapper" procedure that will accept (for example) a string that contains your delimited data and does the conversion and execution for you. Or change "a UI" to be smarter.

Comment: @SMor that is what I have come to understand since making this post. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I will mark it as accepted

Comment: For the sake of the thread @SMor response might be the answer, but I just feel like we have to comment that in most cases this is VERY bad idea to use delimited string over Table-valued parameters!

Comment: Yes, you can call this in one line, simply add semi-colons between your 3 statements, and remove the carriage returns.  You can execute multiple statements in a single batch, and if you form the SQL to be executed in the UI then surely this is simply a case of dynamically generating a single line of script?